# Need help identifying this old Bianchi

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Hi can you help me identify what this is ?

I see the following on the frame:
TRE TUBI RINFORZATI
Bianchi Special
Produzione Columbus

The following is on Fork:
Foderi Forcella
Bianchi special Columbus

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's gorgeous, is what it is!  I'd guess mid `80s, the only detraction is the modern-looking flat plastic pedals.

Comment: If the derailleur is original equipment, it would be for the 1984 model year. https://www.disraeligears.co.uk/site/campagnolo_triomphe_1st_style_0102055_triomphe_corsa_derailleur.html

Comment: Check the handlebar stem. There should be a line stamped on the stem indicating how far into the fork the stem should be inserted. It looks like the handlebars are up too high.

Comment: @Noise I can't find any evidence of that derailleur being used as original equipment.  The closest match i can find is a 1984 Nuovo Racing which puts it in a similar time frame.  Maybe a mid season respec from manufacturer, maybe bike sold in another region, or maybe has already been restored/upgraded once.

Comment: @DavidD it must be a special stem of some type eg Nitto tall Technomic because any normal length would have fallen out if raised that much

Answer (score 1):

Bianchi Stelvio (1985), according to Bicycling Magazine: https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1219169-road-test-bike-review-1985-entry-level-racing-bikes.html